# Backup of ubuntu 12.10 from windows

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, backup

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 from wubi in windows 7.
Now I want to format my system. And again install both.
So, how I can backup my ubuntu updates and restore them later??

Comment: Will this install be another Wubi install or Dual boot?  I would recommend Dual boot as with Wubi as windows problem can break your Ubuntu: this is much less likely with a separate partition.  If you going to do a dual boot you will need to backup to an external drive while running Ubuntu.  You will also find it easier to install Windows then Ubuntu as Windows assumes its the only OS and overwrites the MBR.  You can fix it but if you install Ubuntu last it will give you the option of installing next to Windows and there is nothing to fix later.

Comment: I've installed in another partition and of course Dual boots.. Anyway **Thanx for Help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to installation folder in windows and copy Ubuntu files. Default is `Program files`. When you wanted to recover it, just copy them back.

Comment: If I do so it occupies 16gb hard drive space as I've allocated 16gb to ubuntu. **So is there any other way?**

Comment: Backup always occupies space.

Comment: Ya I know that. Bt if compressed backup option is available, I'm looking forward to it.